# Socket.io event listener not working on client side

Tags: sockets, socket.io

this is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('testerEvent', function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('testerEvent', { description: 'A custom event named testerEvent!'});
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

In index.html listener not working on client side but working on server side.
I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not listening to any events because you are not telling it from where to listen to.
try this:

```
var connectionOptions = {

"force new connection": true,
"reconnectionAttempts": "infinity",
"timeout": 10000,
"transports": ["websocket"]
};
const socket = io(/*your server*/, connectionOptions);
```

Comment: thanks its working now!
But now other issue is that socket.emit('testerEvent', { description: 'A custom event named testerEvent!'}); is not working on client side.
What can be the solution?

Comment: @AbuHurairaLakdawala try this io.set('transports', ['websocket']) before creating the connection.

Comment: its not working...
actually emit and on function together does not work on client side.
Do u know the solution ?